# How to use Amazon S3 classes with Walrus S3?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, amazon-s3, ios4

I am developing an iphone project in which I have to use Walrus S3 of Eucalyptus which my client has asked to use. It is similar to Amazon S3.
He has provided me a url for storing buckets and objects just like there is a url in Amazon S3.

I am using the S3 classes from the following link:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3

There is some sample code given on that link for creating buckets,creating objects etc. .I tried that code.
but after the line
[request startSynchronous];

When I check for the request's response status code ,I get 403.
I am not able to understand how to use these classes.
If anyone has used this before please help me out!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem is resolved.The changes are to be made in the request url for Walrus.